# Could Graphite Edge from the light novel "Accel World" be Kirito from "Sword Art Online"?

Tags: sword-art-online, accel-world

Main indicators for that would be the names of similar fighting techniques. The time difference is not too big for him to still be alive... or are *Accel World* and *Sword Art Online* really in completely separate universes? After all there have been several crossovers.